# Opening links on Mac Chrome app in Incognito Mode

Tags: macos, terminal, google-chrome

Is there a way to open a certain link with Chrome app Incognito Mode using the Terminal app on my Mac? (I want to input the link in the command as well).

Answer (score 2):

To open a certain link with Google Chrome, use this command in terminal:

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome 'http://example.com' --incognito
```

Simply edit http://example.com to any other URL you want to use.

Comment: Does it work when the app is already launched ? I don't have an OSX next to me.

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler Yes it does. With the default settings, it opens a new tab.

Comment: I mean does it open a new window if you're not in incognito mode ?

Comment: If you're not in Incognito Mode it will open a new window.

Comment: Suprisingly it works unlike I thought, great !

Comment: @user770 Here's a list of available flags: https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/ I believe you are looking for `--start-fullscreen`